# Rsync over SFTP alternatives?

Tags: bash, ssh, rsync, sftp, powershell

I am currently working with an SFTP server and aiming to synchronize its folder with a corresponding local directory. It's crucial to note that I lack control over the SFTP server, and files within it are consistently added and removed autonomously. Consequently, my objective is to retrieve these files without overwriting those already transferred.

Initially, I contemplated two approaches:

- Develop a script manually, incorporating a caching mechanism to track already transferred files and initiate synchronization for new additions.
- Discover a tool that could streamline this process, leading me to consider rsync.

However, I encountered a challenge as shell access is restricted, and my assumption that rsync could operate over SFTP was proven incorrect. Below is an example of the rsync command I attempted:

```
rsync -av --ignore-existing \
  -e 'sshpass -p$($password) ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' \
  $username@$username:$remoteBaseDirectory/ $localBaseDirectory"
```

Unfortunately, this command won't work because rsync is not installed on the SFTP server.

Now, my question is:
How can I establish a reliable synchronization process, with a particular interest in the "--ignore-existing" option, without having to build it from scratch?

I usually do powershell in Ubuntu, but is not a problem if the enviromment needs to be changed.

Thank you very much, and have a great day.

Best regards,

Comment: I suppose you could set up SSHFS to mount a filesystem over SFTP (see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh), then use `rsync` as needed.\

Comment: Are you sure that's why the command failed? You are using `username@username` which seems odd, and you seem to be trying to execute the password `$($password)`.